# How to include wp-load.php and have all plugins load as well

Tags: wp-load.php

Why load wp-load.php 'use wordpress ajax instead'

no

This is for testing only. I have a test page I use for local development only, e.g. `test.php` in my themes folder

Now when I do this:

```
global $wpdb;
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../wp-load.php');
get_header();
...
get_footer();
```

I notice that the plugin hooks are not executed, all my scripts and css arent loaded

is there something that I can do, so the plugin hooks load as well?

I tried as well to include my plugin file manually, but doesn't work.

E.g.

`require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../plugins/myplugin-plugin/myplugin-plugin.php');`

doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Why do you need to load `wp-load.php`? If you're testing, you don't need to create a `test.php` and load it directly in the browser, there are far better ways, **easier ways** of doing these things. Case in point you've ran into all these problems, there's a reason people are telling you to use Admin AJAX, or the superior REST API. What is it that you're testing?

Comment: @TomJNowell to have access to the wordpress functions like `get_header()`. You know, i'm upset, it's in my question, i'm down voted for no reason. You recommend rest api, and ajax. Both are no proper solution to the access to that function

Comment: You provided no context, are you trying to test theme templates? If so, is a page template not an appropriate solution that avoids this? Or a virtual page via rewrite rules? A `home.php`? Fundamentally what you're asking for is usually done by people who don't know about Admin AJAX or how to handle forms properly. Unless you say why you're trying to do this, people will assume that, after all you're behaving exactly the same as somebody who's stubborn and wants to use it for AJAX. There are better ways to test template functions

Comment: @TomJNowell well maybe that would work too, but that wasn't my question. Maybe I don't want to add a db entry for a test page into my app but just I file I can simply add and remove and be done with it? maybe I want to call from a different framework, outside of the wordpress world, maybe I want to use a cron that is not the buggy `wp_cron`. I appreciate your efforts. But the question is clear and valid. A down vote is a witch hunt.

Comment: You don't need to add a DB entry, not that it would incur any kind of cost. It would have been better to ask for a solution to your problem of testing template functions in a lightweight and easy manner. Instead, you devised a solution, but it didn't work so you asked for a solution to your solution to your problem, aka an XY problem. Eitherway it sounds like you have a very specific use case, but you're hiding it from us for some reason. If you wanted to call `get_header` from a different framework, why didn't you ask that?

Comment: I'd also advise against calling `get_header` in a cron or CLI context, in those contexts there may not be a main loop, which can cause problems when theme templates are loaded. If this is for CI or other automated testing, this isn't how you would do that either

Comment: @TomJNowell I appreciate your efforts. The question is though: What is `8^2` you can then go ahead and say well why dont you just do `64+0` same result. Well well... that wasn't my question. If I give you a reason, you can start to complain that the reason is not good enough, just like you did.

Comment: Look, you're asking how to do something that's bad practice without explaining what you're trying to do. The chances of it being answered as a result are very low, hence down votes. Instead, explain what you're trying to do in the first place, there are almost certainly superior solutions that are easier and faster. The problem is I can't figure out what your end use case is because you're being deliberately vague, but I can tell you with 100% certainty what you're trying to do is wrong

Comment: e.g. you could add a 3 line code snippet to your `functions.php` that loaded a template in your theme that would do the same thing, but work flawlessly, but that might not be what you're trying to do, you won't provide context, and without context it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @TomJNowell this question is 100% valid. It is bad practice? its for testing. It should be an atomic test. A sandbox, a little playground outside of having to go to `wp-admin` add and delete posts to run a little test. Messing with the `functions.php` is seriously bad advice for testing. You call it bad practice? well the whole wordpress thing isn't really a good practice anyway is it?

Comment: if it's an automated atomic test then why didn't you say so, that's an enormous help. There is indeed a superior option that works much better with automated tests. No need to get angry, just be open to better options and evaluate them. You're not the only person to encounter these things. If it's for experimentation, there are better solutions

Comment: ( also, it wasn't me who downvoted )

Comment: How would you expect template functions to behave when there's no request or query object? Anyway, if you want a simple answer as to why just including `wp-load.php` does nothing, open the file `wp-blog-header.php` in the root WordPress directory and see.

Answer (score 0):

Note that simply bootstrapping directly for a one off temporary file is never the optimal solution, and bad practice, and tends to introduce lots of problems. E.g. in your case, you might have WordPress functions available, but no theme files or APIs are triggered.

Instead, there are better ways to do it. This isn't considered bad practice without reason.

#### In a Browser

If you want to mess around with templates, and don't want to create page templates, you can put this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function($template) {
    return isset($_GET['test']) ? locate_template(['test.php']) : $template ;
}, 99 );
```

Now, when you visit `yoursite.com/?test`, it will load the `test.php` template in your theme.

You could even expand this further:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function($template) {
    return !empty($_GET['test']) ? locate_template(['test/'.$_GET['test'].'.php') : $template ;
}, 99 );
```

Now you can place any PHP file inside a `test` sub folder in your theme, and access it via `yoursite.com/?test=foo` to load `test/foo.php`. As a bonus, you no longer need to count how many folders up `wp-load.php` is, and it will work on any WP install no matter how the folders are configured

Just don't do this on a live server.

#### In CLI

Additionally, if you have WP CLI installed, you can run `wp eval test.php` to do this from the command line.

You can also run `wp shell` to get an interactive PHP shell with WP functions loaded, and to test cron jobs, you can run `wp cron test`.

#### In a Cron Job, or Another Template

You can run `get_template_part('test')` to load the `test.php` template from somewhere else in WP.

You can also use `wp cron event run --due-now` to trigger WP Cron via an actual cron job. There's no need to bootstrap WordPress from a PHP file to get reliable cron in WordPress.

#### In Automated Testing

In general, you would not test templates this way. A proper test would either create posts, or mock posts. This is usually done by spawning a test environment, and pre-filling it with a database of known content, and running tests, reverting the database to the known good example in the process.

Doing this allows for integration tests using tools such as Behat which run automated browser tests by spawning headless browsers such as phantom, or even firefox instances.

Alternatively, for testing classes, you could use standard PHPUnit, combined with mocks for the WP APIs used.

Keep in mind that most major production themes on enterprise sites have some sort of `tests` subfolder that gets ran by `phpunit` or some other CI tool